# Count words in a document and output to excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have about 10 Word documents labeled (1,2,3 etc.). I have a requirement to count the number of words and the number of misspelled words in each document and output this count to Excel.

How do I write a VBA script for this?

In word I know how to find out the word count and the number of misspelled words and display that as a Msgbox, but I'm not sure how to make excel read through word documents and display the output.

Ideally, the excel file will to ask me to select all the word documents, and then produce a sheet that has:

```
Doc Name   Word_count   Misspelled_count
1              30            9
2              45            8
3              50            15
.
.
```

My VBA code in Word to display error and word count is:

```
Sub get_wpm_errorcount()
Dim ThisDoc As Document
Dim ErrorCnt As Integer
Dim WordCnt As Integer

Set ThisDoc = ActiveDocument

WordCnt = ThisDoc.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
ErrorCnt = ThisDoc.SpellingErrors.Count
MsgBox ("WPM = " & WordCnt & "   Error Count = " & ErrorCnt)

End Sub
```

EDIT:
I tried my hand at this and this is what I came up with ..

```
Dim RunErrorCount As Integer    'Global running total of errors
Dim FilesToOpen                 'Global list of files to open
Dim FileCount As Integer        'Global count of files to open

Private Sub ReadtextFile()

Dim x As Integer
Dim wkbAll As Workbook
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:="All Files (*.*),*.*", _
    MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No Files were selected"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If

x = 1

Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))

Call get_wpm_errorcount

Range("A1").Offset(FileCount + 1, 0).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
ActiveCell.Value = FilesToOpen(x).Name  'Output filename

Range("B1").Offset(FileCount + 1, i).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
ActiveCell.Value = WordCount  'Output total count

Range("C1").Offset(FileCount + 1, i).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
ActiveCell.Value = ErrorCount  'Output total count

x = x + 1

FileCount = UBound(FilesToOpen)

End Sub

Sub get_wpm_errorcount(ThisDoc As Object)
Dim ErrorCnt As Integer
Dim WordCnt As Integer

WordCnt = ThisDoc.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
ErrorCnt = ThisDoc.SpellingErrors.Count

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be pretty easy. Modify as needed.

You need your Excel to open (and then control) Word.  This is called "binding".  The example below will bind Word to Excel:

```
Option Explicit
'NOTE: REQUIRES REFERENCE TO MS WORD
Sub main()
Dim wordApp as Word.Application
Dim wordDoc as Word.Document
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim listFiles As Variant
Dim i As Long

'Display the file dialog to allow the user to select file(s)
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
    fd.ButtonName = "Select Files to Process"
    fd.Show

'Create Word Application only if needed:
If fd.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'Then iterate th selected items and open them in Word:
For i = 1 to fd.SelectedItems.Count

    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fd.SelectedItems(i))  


    'Send the document object AND the integer i to the other function
    ' which will read the document and print results to Excel spreadsheet
    Call get_wpm_errorcount(wordDoc, i)

    wordDoc.Close
Next

Set wordApp = Nothing


End Sub

Sub get_wpm_errorcount(ThisDoc As Object, itemNumber as Integer)
Dim ErrorCnt As Integer
Dim WordCnt As Integer

WordCnt = ThisDoc.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
ErrorCnt = ThisDoc.SpellingErrors.Count

Range("A1").Offset(itemNumber, 0).Value = WordCnt
Range("B1").Offset(itemNumber, 0).Value = ErrorCnt

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried my hand at binding. I am extremely new to VBA so I still have trouble figuring this out.

Again, I would like Excel to read a Bunch of Word files. Not just a specific one. I would then like to OUTPUT in Excel..

Comment: See the revision which will handle multiple files. You will need to modify the procedure `get_wpm_errorCount` to write the output to Excel worksheet, instead of displaying in MessageBox.

Comment: You can also use `CreateObject("Word.Application")` without setting a reference to word.

Comment: @SO yes, you can. But you cannot `Dim wordApp as Word.Application` *without* the reference :)  Early-binding is usually easier for beginners especially because of the intellisense.

Comment: @david-zemens For printing to excel, do I declare i as a global variable and then add this to `get_wpm_errorCount`
(
`Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value = WordCnt
Range("B1").Offset(i, 0).Value = ErrorCnt`)

Comment: No need to declare it global/public. Just pass `i` as an additional argument. I'll make the revision, give me 2 minutes :)

Comment: No problem. You seem to have a pretty good handle on the basics, just a matter of learning some tricks & implementing it.

Comment: Also if this has solved your problem, do consider upvoting or accepting the answer :)

Comment: @david-zemens Thank you David! the code compiled when i changed definitions to`dim wordapp as object` and `dim worddoc as object`. After it compiled it comes back with an error saying  `wdStatisticWords` is undefined. Is it because this is Word specific VBA and unrecognized by excel?

Comment: Yes, that's why I specifically mention that you must include a reference to Word's object model :)  in the Visual Basic Editor, from the Tools menu, choose References and then check the box for your version of MS Word. Otherwise, you have to define `wdStatisticWords` as a variable or constant expression and assign it the appropriate value.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!